# Use leaflet to display 45° Imagery

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, openstreetmap, projection

Assuming I had 45° Imagery similar to Google's (I want to draw them by hand, it's a small project) is it possible to use leaflet to display a map in a similar manner Google does?

The problem is that I use OSM data to display markers and building outlines on the map but since the 45° Imagery is tilted it requires different projection (at least that's what I think).

Is there a simple way of creating a projection that would allow me to correctly display existing OSM data on top of 45° tiles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if projections apply here, but you could try [Leaflet.imageTransform](https://github.com/ScanEx/Leaflet.imageTransform) and transform the image to match the OSM projection.